# How to use apply instead of for loop for stringMatch function?

Tags: r, for-loop, string-matching, apply

I'm trying to calculate the number of pairwise differences between a long list of sequences, and put it back into a matrix form. This is a toy example of what I want to do.

```
library(MiscPsycho)
b <- c("-BC", "ACB", "---") # Toy example of sequences
workb <- expand.grid(b,b)
new <- c(1:9)

# Need to get rid of this for loop somehow
for (i in 1:9) {
new[i] <- stringMatch(workb[i,1], workb[i,2], normalize="NO")
}

workb <- cbind(workb, new)
newmat <- reShape(workb$new, id=workb$Var1, colvar=workb$Var2)

a <- c("Subject1", "Subject2", "Subject3") #Relating it back to the subject ID
colnames(newmat) <- a
rownames(newmat) <- a
newmat
```

I'm not very familiar with using the apply functions, but I'd like to use it to be able to replace the for loop, which will probably get slow considering I have a large number of sequences. (The stringMatch function is from MiscPsycho). Please let me know how to make it more efficient!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way to make the code more efficient? The different solutions below work well for short sequences, but I have a few hundred sequences and I'm trying to construct a pairwise difference matrix for them, and the sequences each have the same length (about 300 characters). When I use the code below, it takes over half an hour just to make a matrix comparing 20 sequences...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get those "pairwise distances" I would have done something like:

```
  Vm <- Vectorize(stringMatch)
  nex <- outer(b,b, FUN=Vm, normalize = "NO")
 nex
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    3    2
[2,]    3    0    3
[3,]    2    3    0
```

Comment: I only think of it when I get messages like this one: `Error in outer(b, b, FUN = stringMatch) : 
  dims [product 9] do not match the length of object [1]`

Comment: Thanks so much!! That works great, and it's much more efficient than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the loop

```
new <- apply(workb, 1, function(x) stringMatch(x[[1]],x[[2]], normalize="NO"))
```

Comment: Great, thanks!! That was what I was hoping to write, but I just got confused about the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function that takes your index, `i`, and returns `new[i]`.

```
myfun <- function(i) {
  stringMatch(workb[i, 1], workb[i, 2], normalize='NO')
}
```

Then you can `apply` along your new vector:

```
workb$new <- unlist(lapply(new, myfun))
```

In general, you are using a `for loop` correctly in R.  You have allocated the vector `new` before hand and are filling it rather than growing it.